# Count keys in array

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I've written the below function, it takes in a 2 dimensional array and return the number of times a key occurs, BUT it feels like i may be reinventing the wheel here, is there an easy way?

```
function countKeys($array, $key)
{
  $results = array();

  foreach($array as $row)
  {
    if (array_key_exists($row[$key], $results))
    {
      $results[$row[$key]] += 1;
    }
    else
    {
      $results[$row[$key]] = 1;
    }
  }

  return $results;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. It is a little cleaner and may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the keys in a two dimensional array with a search I would do this -

```
function countKeys($array,$search){
    $key_count = array(); // new array
    foreach($array as $record) {  
        $keys = array_keys($record);
        foreach($keys as $key){
            if($key == $search){ // check against the search term
                array_push($key_count, $key); // add the key to the new array
            }
        }
    }
    return count($key_count); // just count the new array
}
echo countKeys($records, 'last_name');
```

[EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/0puq-jz98)

[`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)
[`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: OP states 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

For a 2 dimensional array try:

```
$result = count(array_column($array, $key));
```

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [**PHP Implementation of array_column()**](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

Answer (score -1):

Just use count() function like:

```
count($array);
```

see:  http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php

You can use this function to count arrays variable as well.

Hope it helps you.